# How to edit a record(s) with multiple form xpage?

Tags: xpages

I have an xpage that allows the user to choose a customer and then order products for that customer.  It's not a simple xpage that created a document, uses a view control to view it and re-edits it.  It will be used on the web and in the client.  How do I fill in all the data for the various fields when the user wants to look at their order for a company since there are multiple documents that make up that xpage?  Is there automatic processes or do I need to do it manually?

Comment: Mike, this sounds like something you will have to do manually in code.

Answer (score 0):

The best method is to use multiple datasources (the Notes documents) each with a different datasource name. When saved, be sure to save each of the datasources that have a change. Also, it is helpful to mark to "ignoreRequestParameters", so each one acts independently.

I have found that using the dynamic content control useful when doing things like this, it seems to reduce the number of replication/save conflicts.

Comment: Would I change the "input" xpage for the order or create a new xPage with less "Create" functionality but only edit certain areas of it?

Comment: You could, depending on what you needed. I know that doesn't quite answer. But if you can have input boxes for those fields that need new input, and put labels or disabled boxes for those you don't. You can also compute if the editbox is read only or disabled based on what is needed to enter, giving your clients a clue. Dynamic Content lets you show just bits, so you could put different controls in depending on what was to be entered.